# JSON_AGG automatically sorting data

Tags: postgresql

On running the below query data coming from JSON_AGG gets automatically sorted. But I do not want to sort data.
What can I do ?

```
select  r.id, r.name, r.description,  
                    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT tags.name, ',')as tags,
                    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT i.name, ',') as ingredient,
                    JSON_AGG(DISTINCT mb.name ) as macros,
                    JSON_AGG(DISTINCT mb.value) as val
                    from recipe r
                    left join recipe_tags tags on  r.id  = tags.recipe_id
                    left join  recipe_breakdown rb on r.id = rb.recipe_id 
                    left join  ingredient i on  rb.ingredient_id = i.id
                    left join recipe_master_breakdown mb on mb.recipe_id = r.id
                    GROUP by r.id limit 20;
```

Below is an example of of output where macros and value columns are automatically sorted by the above query.

[image: output]

And the original result for macros and values are in below image[image: output 2].

Comment: The data is not "sorted" because you are not using an ORDER BY together with `json_agg()`. So any order you see is pure coincidence. If you don't care about the order, then why is this result a problem?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I edited my question please refer to that., In the second image that have original data, have different values with respective macros. But in the first image it is changed because of the query.

Comment: Rows in a table have no implied sort order so that proves nothing. Any order you see is pure coincidence. But again: if you don't care about the order, then why is the order you get a problem? (The order in the array is probably of the way DISTINCT is implemented)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the default order of records for a SELECT statement in MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/what-is-the-default-order-of-records-for-a-select-statement-in-mysql) Although it mentions MySQL, it's true for all DBMSs. Unless you specify `ORDER BY` all bets are off, the ordering is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

You can order by any row when you use most aggregation functions. Here is a sample query with different orders per field;

```
SELECT
    r.id,
    r.name,
    r.description,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT tags.name, ',' ORDER BY tags.name) AS tags,
    STRING_AGG(DISTINCT i.name, ',' ORDER BY i.id) AS ingredient,
    JSON_AGG(DISTINCT mb.name ORDER BY mb.id) AS macros,
    JSON_AGG(DISTINCT mb.value ORDER BY mb.id) AS val
  FROM recipe r
  LEFT JOIN recipe_tags tags ON r.id = tags.recipe_id
  LEFT JOIN recipe_breakdown rb ON r.id = rb.recipe_id
  LEFT JOIN ingredient i ON rb.ingredient_id = i.id
  LEFT JOIN recipe_master_breakdown mb ON mb.recipe_id = r.id
  GROUP BY
    r.id
  LIMIT 20;
```

For further reading check [Aggregate Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) section of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it is due to the DISTINCT. One of the ways a system can remove duplicates is to sort the values, then ignore any value that's the same as the preceding one.

Removing that keyword is unlikely to solve the issue. First any duplicates will show (although your test data has none). More importantly the constructed JSON arrays are independent and not guaranteed to be in the same order.

I think you should GROUP BY recepie, name & macro, SUMming val. Within the JSON_AGGs order by macro. If you edit the question to include a [reproducible example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) someone *may* be willing to work out details.