# Random Order of Numbers in Select Statement

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, order-by

In the case where you've specified the following list of numbers, which are in random order, will the results be in the same order?

```
where item in
(
    371355,
    371476,
    371629,
    370556,
    370677,
    370820,
    370952,
    371070,
    371223,
    372154,
    372253,
    371751,
    371872
)
```

Comment: No. If there is no `ORDER BY` in the query, the results can be in arbitrary order. See a similar question: [Does an IOT guarantee order in a select?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14570/does-an-iot-guarantee-order-in-a-select/14571#14571) that has the same exact answer: **"The only thing that guarantees result set order is an `ORDER BY` clause in your query."**

Answer (score 3):

NO,

If you do want them to be in order (`asc`, `desc`) here is how you would query it...

```
SELECT T.ITEM
FROM TABLE T
WHERE T.ITEM IN ( 371355
              , 371476
              , 371629
              , 370556
              , 370677
              , 370820
              , 370952
              , 371070
              , 371223
              , 372154
              , 372253
              , 371751
              , 371872
              )
ORDER BY T.ITEM DESC
```